# SVD: why are the results different: hand-calculation and Matlab computation?

Tags: svd

I am solving a SVD computatiob question.

The following matrix is given: `A=`:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1.5 & 0.5 &  0&0 \\ 
0.5 & 1.5 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1.5 & 0.5\\ 
 0&0  & 0.5 & 1.5
\end{bmatrix}$$
 I have taken the `SVD(A) = [ U S V]`. My computation of the matrix S is the same with Matlab, V and U are different. 
 I have checked a solution in the book, my result is correct.

$$V=\begin{bmatrix}
0.5 & 0.5 & 0.5&0.5 \\ 
0.5 & 0.5 & -0.5 & -0.5\\ 
0.5 & -0.5 & -0.5& 0.5\\ 
0.5&-0.5 & 0.5 & -0.5
\end{bmatrix}$$

Is there another way, how to find `V` matrix from SVD in Matlab?

Comment: I don't have access to MATLAB right now, but the U and V in the SVD decomposition are not unique, so it is possible that you and Matlab are both correct.

Comment: @slimmerikko Do you know another way to compute `V` ?

Comment: Yes you can for example use the SVD of $I_2$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1.5&0.5\\0.5&1.5\end{bmatrix}$ combined with the properties of Kronecker products.

Comment: @mathreadler Could you please give to me more details?

Comment: @NoelMiller https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Abstract%20properties

Comment: @mathreadler Do you mean: $ kron(V_{svd(I_2)},V_{A_{part}}]$?

Comment: Ehm, yeah, but also singular values themselves are products like this.

Answer (score 1):

When looking at the singular values of $A$, we see $\sigma(A) = (2,2,1,1)$ so there are two sets of double singular values.

Given two singular vectors $u_1$ and $u_2$ with $A u_1 = \sigma_1 v_1$ and $A u_2= \sigma_1 v_2$, then $\tilde{u} = c_1u_1 + c_2 u_2$ is a singular vector to that singular vlaue $\sigma_1$ as well. 
This can be seen by $$A\tilde{u} = c_1Au_1 + c_2 Au_2 = \sigma_1 \cdot (c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2) = \sigma_1 \tilde{v}_1$$